# Is Force Lightning just Electrokinesis?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Well we know that Force Lightning is generally considered a Dark Side ability in both Canon and Legends, we also know that there was a Light Side variant of the power known as Electric Judgement/Emerald Lightning, and I also know the Baran Do Sages had their own version called 'white lightning technique' so is Force Lightning just manipulating/generating electricity or is it something else entirely?

> Force lightning was a well known Force ability used most often by
> practitioners of the dark side of the Force, especially the Sith. The
> ability was commonly referred to as Sith lightning due to the
> affiliations of its typical users and manipulation of **lightning**.
>
> Electric Judgment, also known as Emerald Lightning, was a Force
> technique used by the Jedi to spray **electric** bolts of variable
> intensity from the hands and fingers.

> They were also proficient in a white **lightning** technique, possibly a
> variation of Electric Judgment.